# Тестирование ПО

Tags: тестирование

Учусь в университете на кафедре вычислительной математики и кибернетики. Заинтересовался тестированием, хотелось бы узнать как изучать данную сферу, на что ориентироваться, что прочитать, как практиковаться и т.д.

Стоит ли развиваться в данной сфере? Насколько сложно и интересно? Долго ли нужно учиться чтобы хоть как-то начать работать над какими-либо проектами?

Comment: На мой взгляд, это не особо интересная область. Обычно в тестировщики  (только не путайте  с разработкой систем тестирования) попадают те, кто не смог стать разработчиком

Answer (score 0):

На примере вашего вопроса можно разобрать как работает проверяющий работоспособность ПО.

> Стоит ли развиваться в данной сфере?

- Кому развиваться?
- Кому именно стоит?
- В какой именно "сфере"?

> Насколько сложно и интересно?

- Сложно для кого?
- Сложно по сравнению с чем?
- Интересно для кого?
- Интересно в сравнении с чем?

> Долго ли нужно учиться чтобы хоть как-то начать работать над какими-либо проектами?

- Долго это сколько? Час, день, год, 10 лет?
- Хоть как-то начать работать — это как? Запятые в справке к ПО можно с первого часа исправлять, например.
- Над какими-либо "проектами"? Можно начать работать над любым с таким подходом, опять-таки, разыскивая неправильно расставленные запятые в справке (тоже проверка). Так что, над какими именно всё-таки?

Вот в целом, чем занимается проверяющий ПО, т.е. его работа — придираться. Ваш же вопрос будет закрыт как общий, ибо, как вы могли заметить, он слишком расплывчатый и не точный.

Comment: *`"его работа — придираться"`* -- теоретически, наверное, так правильно. На практике же, тестирование это поверка соответствия программно-аппаратного комплекса набору спецификаций